# Bash script to find and list duplicate instances of python

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script to find duplicate instances of python scripts running on a Pi. The following script is working and identifies the Python (not Python3 intentionally) of duplicates instances of the same script. I get the PID as expected but I am not able to get the full path and name of the script.

I have created a couple instance of a script:

```
bms       9189  0.0  0.1  10592  7248 ?        S    09:11   0:00 python -u /home/bms/Dev/APItest/APItest.py
bms       9192  0.0  0.1  10592  7188 ?        S    09:12   0:00 python -u /home/bms/Dev/APItest/APItest.py
```

This is the output I get from the bash script:

```
Found 2 instances of -u:
PID: 9189, Script path: -u
PID: 9192, Script path: -u
Finished checking for duplicate Python scripts.
```

I was expecting to get an output like:

```
PID: 9189, Script path: home/bms/Dev/APItest/APItest.py
PID: 9192, Script path: home/bms/Dev/APItest/APItest.py
```

And this is the script I am using:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get a list of all running Python processes
PYTHON_PROCESSES=$(ps aux | grep '[p]ython' | grep -v 'python3' | awk '{print $2}')

# Loop through the Python processes and count how many times each script is running
declare -A SCRIPT_COUNTS
declare -A SCRIPT_PIDS
for PID in $PYTHON_PROCESSES; do
    CMD=$(ps -p $PID -o comm=)
    if [ "$CMD" == "python" ]; then
        SCRIPT_ARGS=$(ps -p $PID -o args=)
        SCRIPT_PATH=$(echo "$SCRIPT_ARGS" | awk '{print $2}')
        SCRIPT_NAME=${SCRIPT_PATH##*/}
        if [ -z "${SCRIPT_COUNTS[$SCRIPT_NAME]}" ]; then
            SCRIPT_COUNTS[$SCRIPT_NAME]=0
        fi
        ((SCRIPT_COUNTS[$SCRIPT_NAME]++))
        if [ -z "${SCRIPT_PIDS[$SCRIPT_NAME]}" ]; then
            SCRIPT_PIDS[$SCRIPT_NAME]=""
        fi
        SCRIPT_PIDS[$SCRIPT_NAME]="${SCRIPT_PIDS[$SCRIPT_NAME]}$PID:$SCRIPT_PATH "
    fi
done

# Loop through the script counts and print the names of any scripts that have     duplicates
for SCRIPT_NAME in "${!SCRIPT_COUNTS[@]}"; do
    COUNT=${SCRIPT_COUNTS[$SCRIPT_NAME]}
    if [ $COUNT -gt 1 ]; then
        echo "Found $COUNT instances of $SCRIPT_NAME:"
        for INSTANCE in ${SCRIPT_PIDS[$SCRIPT_NAME]}; do
            PID=${INSTANCE%%:*}
            SCRIPT_PATH=${INSTANCE#*:}
            echo "PID: $PID, Script path: $SCRIPT_PATH"
        done
       fi
    done

echo "Finished checking for duplicate Python scripts."
```

Apologise if there is any misalignment in the code. Had to adjust it manually to fit it in the canvas.
My question is: what should I change to get the desired output ( PID plus full path and name of the duplicates).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @GillesQuénot It is not a code/data/error. It is a screenshot of the files I am processing in terminal. I think it is necessary to clarify the question.

Comment: This is the same. Cppy your output as text, not images. That way, we can use the input to test your code.  
Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @GillesQuénot, ok got it. Sorry for that. Fixed

Comment: [Don't use UPPER case variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this simple [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) ?

```
$ <INPUT> | awk '{print "PID: " $2 ", Script path: " $NF}' file
PID: 9189, Script path: /home/bms/Dev/APItest/APItest.py
PID: 9192, Script path: /home/bms/Dev/APItest/APItest.py
```